# ReplaceWith linq xml dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Can someone help me with this work. 
we have file xml file 
test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  Lorem ipsum <key name="k1"/>
  <local> <template> guest=<key name="k1"/> </template> </local>
  <template>
    Hello <key name="k1"/>.
    Goodbye <key name="k2"/>.
    End
    <key name="k3"/>
  </template>
</root>
```

On file, we have node "template", we must search node "key" with attribute name and replace it by dictionary key-pair-value. And save it in  test.out.xml

```
<root>
  Lorem ipsum <key name="k1"/>
  <local> guest=Alice </local>
  Hello Alice.
  Goodbye Bob.
  End
  <key name="k3"/>
</root>
```

Using Dictionary and  Linq to xml.
My code

```
    foreach (var elements in xdoc.Descendants("template").ToList().Elements("key"))
    {
        elements.Attribute("name").Parent.ReplaceWith(dict.Where(x
            => elements.Attribute("name").Value == x.Key).Select(p => p.Value));;
    }
```

and my output

```
  Lorem ipsum <key name="k1" /><local><template> guest=Alice</template></local><template>
    Hello Alice.
    Goodbye <key name="k2" />.
    End
    <key name="k3" /></template></root>
```

problem is, i changed by key in dictonary by value in name attribute, 
but  i cant remove template in file :(
p.s.
sorry my bad english

Comment: Did my answer help you resolve your issue? if so, please mark it as accepted by ticking the V to its left. If not, let me know and I'll try to further help you with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. If you had separated between the iteration over `template` elements and the iteration over `key` elements, I think you would have immediately noticed the solution.

So here it is:

```
var replacers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "k1", "Alice" }, { "k2", "Bob" }, { "k3", "Carol" } };
var templates = xdoc.Root.Descendants("template").ToList();
foreach (var template in templates)
{
    var toReplace = template.Descendants("key").ToList();
    foreach (var element in toReplace)
    {
        element.ReplaceWith(replacers[element.Attribute("name").Value]);  
    }
    template.ReplaceWith(template.Value);
}
```